# Is it good practice to make static find methods in Doctrine models

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

Sometimes I have complicated find procedures and I'm feeling dirty to repeat this code in my Controller.

Now I am thinking, it is possible to do something like this:

```
class User extends BaseUser
{

    private static function getTable()
    {
        return Doctrine_Core::getTable('User');
    }

    public static function findAll()
    {
        return getTable()->findAll();
    }

    public function currentEnrolments() {
        $query = Doctrine_Query::create()
                ->from('Enrolment e')
                ->where('e.user_id = ?', $this->id)
                ->addWhere('e.finish_date IS NULL');
        return $query->execute();
    }

}
```

Is this a good practice? Or should I only put non static members like the query I have shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, if it saves you time, there nothing to lose and every minute you can save to gain.

Functions like `getTable` and `findAll` are probably not saving you a lot, but custom queries for finding stuff more specific to your application will definitely be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

I have got pretty much the same approach.

- I wouldn't bother with your static proxies of `getTable()` and `findAll()`.

  - That doesn't really add any value to your code
  - I, personnaly, never call `findAll()` on any model object as you will generally need

    - to cross-check against a foreign key
    - paginate / sort
    - ...
- regarding your `currentEnrolments()` function, this is worth doing as you have a bit of logic on this `->addWhere('e.finish_date IS NULL')`, thus explaining you can't use the "magic" Doctrine relation `->Enrolment`. Maybe this is something Doctrine 2 is resolving, need to check this out ...

Regards